# How to track down JavaScript in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple carousel for which I need to modify the delay. When I made the change it didn't have any effect. So I removed all the code related to it and it still continues to work. I can't find any JS anywhere on the page or in a linked file that references this but it's still working. I even changed the ID in the markup but it continues to work. How can I figure out where the JS that's making it work lives?
Thanks!

Comment: Try clearing your cache, maybe you're still getting the old versions of the files?

Comment: No, I checked on that. It's getting the current version.

Comment: Check the network panel of your devtools, you can see which scripts are being loaded in from there.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked there and checked out every script that's being loaded. Nada.

Comment: How are you expecting us to answer this? There isn't anything to work with, the carousel for all we know might be purely done in CSS if there isn't an JS being loaded on the page. Please provide a working example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I think that his question is legit. He's referring to JavaScript implementation, and he just don't know how is that done, and he just wanna find out. No need for vote down. :)

Comment: Thanks @ShP :) I thought it was a reasonable question.

Comment: Attacking the community for following the site rules is not constructive and not going to get your question reopened either. Follow the advice in the close reason instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I don't care. I'm tired of being attacked by somebody every time I ask a question. The "site rules" seem fairly subjective anyway. And like I said, ShP already answered my question. I don't need it reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm always suggesting using firebug for this. You can inspect the element that you want, in your case carousel, and right click on element in HTML tab view, and select wanted action, for example:

[image]

Break on attribute change
Break on element removal 
...

(depends of implementation of that carousel plugin)

And when break-point is hit, you can take a look at call-stack to see from where it's triggered, and there's your JavaScript code.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Perfect! I haven't used Firebug pretty much since Chrome came out. I didn't realize how far it had come. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can set breakpoints, or rather make the runtime stop when certain events fire (in chrome at least). try settings some and use the carousel which should obviously fire some events. then, step though the code and see where you are going ;)

it may be worth a shot